# Proof that higher-order Voronoi diagrams subdivide space

Tags: tessellations, voronoi-diagram

The Wikipedia article on Voronoi diagrams claims that higher-order Voronoi diagrams subdivide space. This is far from obvious. Can anyone point me to a proof?

Comment: What is most confusing to me is that the sets of points can be intermingled and yet still generate a partitioning of the plane.

Comment: You could bounty this question to give it attention again